# Как сделать один из пунктов второго выпадающего списка выбранным, если в первом выбрано отпределенное значение? (код внутри)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два выпадающих списка. Нужно сделать так, чтобы, если в первом списке выбран "Челябинск", то во втором выбиралась "Виноградная", если же выбрано любое другое значение, то автоматически выбирался элемент со значением - 0 ("Второй список").
Сейчас, несмотря на условие, все равно всегда выбирается "Виноградная".

```js
$('#edit-field-sity-tid').change(function() {
  var SVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  var c = $('#edit-field-streets').find('option');
  if (SVal == 710) {
    $('.dependent').css('display', 'block');
    c.val(2).attr('selected', 'selected');
  } else {
    c.val(0).attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('.dependent').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```css
.dependent {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #8F8F8F;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All">Элементы списка</option>
  <option value="708">Златоуст</option>
  <option value="710">Челябинск</option>
</select>
<select id="edit-field-streets" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="0">Второй список</option>
  <option value="1">Каштановая</option>
  <option value="2">Виноградная</option>
</select>
<div class="dependent hide">А я тут для проверки условия))</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего так, или любым другим способом.
Разница `prop` и `attr` наглядно [показана здесь](http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=44).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#edit-field-sity-tid').on('change', function() {

    var SVal = $(this).val();
    var c = $('#edit-field-streets').find('option');

    if (SVal == 710) {
      c.filter("[value=2]").prop('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
      c.filter("[value=0]").prop('selected', 'selected');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="edit-field-sity-tid" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="All">Элементы списка</option>
  <option value="708">Златоуст</option>
  <option value="710">Челябинск</option>
</select>
<select id="edit-field-streets" name="field_sity_tid" class="form-select">
  <option value="0">Второй список</option>
  <option value="1">Каштановая</option>
  <option value="2">Виноградная</option>
</select>
```

Comment: забыл я про prop напрочь :(

Comment: а ведь сталкивался уже с prop. голова моя садовая... Только одну строчку не пойму)) $(this).val(); мы ведь тут к значение селекта обращаемся а его, у селекта нет значений, но почему тогда все работает?)

Comment: есть у него значение, так вы можете узнать, кто выбран, но не можете установить его для изменения выбора

Comment: и вот это `var c = $('#edit-field-streets').find('option');` тогда уж можно заменить на `var c = $('this).find('option');` чтоб еще раз не искать.

Comment: @splash58 нет. `this` относится к первому списку, а в переменную `c` попадает значение из второго.